# Dropdown list actions using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, html-select

I have the following Dropdown List which is not the traditional SELECT and OPTION dropdown list. Using JQUERY, I am wanting to know if there is a way to perform an action when a given option is chosen. EX - When you click the dropdown and choose BIRDS, it will hide some DIV elsewhere on the page. Thank You

```
<section class="main">
    <div class="wrapper">
        <div id="dd" class="wrapper-dropdown-3" tabindex="1">
            <span>View By Category</span>
            <ul class="dropdown">
                <li><a>Dogs</a></li>
                <li><a>Cats</a></li>
                <li><a>Birds</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</section>
```

Comment: `$('div#dd ul.dropdown a').click(function(){alert("Show or hide"+$(this).text());});`

Comment: $('div#dd ul.dropdown li').on('change', function() {var clsName = $(this).attr('class'); $("."+clsName).hide()}); provided your li's should be like; <li class='dogs'><a>Dogs</a></li>
                        <li class='cats'><a>Cats</a></li> ....

Comment: @yjs `li`'s doesn't have a `change` event

Comment: @roullie Sorry, it was mistake...answer below!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

https://jsfiddle.net/o8h4gvgd/5/

use something like this. I hope this will help you.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.dropdown .bird').click(function(){
    $('#section_1').toggle();
    $('#section_1').hide();    
  });
});
```

Comment: I have given you two option toggle and hide, use it according to your need

Comment: I'm sorry, It says I need to earn 15 reputation in order to do this. I certainly would if I could. Thanks Again.

Answer (score 0):

```js
$('div#dd ul.dropdown li a').on('click', function() {var clsName = $(this).parent().attr('name'); $("."+clsName).hide()});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<section class="main">
            <div class="wrapper">
                <div id="dd" class="wrapper-dropdown-3" tabindex="1">
                    <span>View By Category</span>
                    <ul class="dropdown">

                        <li name='dogs'><a href="javascript:">Dogs</a></li>
                        <li name='cats'><a href="javascript:">Cats</a></li>
                        <li name='birds'><a href="javascript:">Birds</a></li>

                </ul>
                </div>
            </div>
        </section>

<div class='dogs'>Div with dogs info</div>
<div class='cats'>Div with cats info</div>
<div class='birds'>Div with birds info</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

give a class to entries like;

```
<li><a class="item">Dogs</a></li>
<li><a class="item">Cats</a></li>
<li><a class="item">Birds</a></li>
```

then, use a `click` event like;

```
$(".item").click(function(){
    item = $(this).text();
    alert(item);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$('#dd ul.dropdown a').click(function() {
var _this = $(this);
var index = $('#dd ul.dropdown a').index(_this);

alert(index);

if (index === 2) {
    alert(_this.text());
    // ..do anything you want 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 $(document).ready(function  () {

    //Your function on what needs to be done on click
    var liClicked = function(obj){
        alert("You Clicked : "+$(obj).html());
    }

    //trigger the onclick based on selected -- in this case '#dd ul.dropdown li a'
    $(document).on("click","#dd ul.dropdown li a", function(){
        //call the above written function
        liClicked(this);
    });

});
```